# cpufrequtils shows my CPU can perform at a higher frequency... why can't I hit max freq?

Tags: debian, cpu, raspberry-pi, cpufreq

I am using a quad-core H2+ Allwinner CPU on my OrangePi Zero. It is 1.2GHz, and I am running Debian server. I've installed cpufrequtils, and am able to modify the governor, which is currently set to `performance`. I have also specified the minimum scaling frequency as 240MHz and the max at 1.2GHz.

A quick output from `cpufreq-info` results in the following:

```
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: cpufreq-sunxi
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0 1 2 3
  maximum transition latency: 2.00 ms.
  hardware limits: 240 MHz - 1.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: interactive, conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 240 MHz and 1.20 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.01 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 60.0 MHz:0.00%, 120 MHz:0.00%, 240 MHz:0.94%, 312 MHz:0.00%, 408 MHz:0.00%, 480 MHz:0.00%, 504 MHz:0.00%, 600 MHz:0.00%, 648 MHz:0.00%, 720 MHz:0.00%, 816 MHz:0.00%, 912 MHz:0.00%, 1.01 GHz:99.06%, 1.10 GHz:0.00%, 1.20 GHz:0.00%, 1.34 GHz:0.00%, 1.44 GHz:0.00%, 1.54 GHz:0.00%  (9)
```

As you can see, my CPU will never actually run at 1.2GHz. I am always at 1.0GHz. I see no limitation to getting there, and my CPU temp is always below 60C.

Does anyone know what is causing my CPU to be unable to achieve 1.2GHz? Thanks!

Comment: Are you expecting the CPU to be maxed out through the activities it is doing?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that I am running a 'sysbench' 4-core CPU stress test at the same time to ensure 100% system load. I inspect activity using 'top' and 'htop', and indeed all cores are at 100%. Concurrent frequency inspection shows 1.0GHz, instead of the hypothetical max 1.2GHz. I also checked the 'time-in-state' for each frequency, and the cores never attempt to go to 1.2GHz, so it isn't an overheating issue.